# Print prints some extra signs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I create a method to print some stuff:

```
def my_print(*str1):
  print '---------------'
  print str1
  print '---------------'


my_print('1fdsfd %s -- %s' % (12, 18))
```

which gives me

```
---------------
('1fdsfd 12 -- 18',)
---------------
```

Why do I have these extra `(` and `)` and even `,` and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Why do you have the asterisk in the `my_print` function definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is due to `*` the `str1` is converted into a tuple inside the `my_print` function, you can either remove the `*` or use `print str1[0]`.

When a `*` is used in functions definition then it behave as a collector, and collects all the  positional arguments passed to function in a tuple.

```
>>> def func(*a):
...     print type(a)
...     print a
...     
>>> func(1)
<type 'tuple'>
(1,)
>>> func(1,2,3)
<type 'tuple'>
(1, 2, 3)
```

Working version of your code:

```
def my_print(str1):
  print '---------------'
  print str1
  print '---------------'


my_print('1fdsfd %s -- %s' % (12, 18))
```

or :

```
def my_print(*str1):
  print '---------------'
  print str1[0]
  print '---------------'


my_print('1fdsfd %s -- %s' % (12, 18))
```

Comment: Probably the OP thought that doing `print a,b,c` or `t=a,b,c; print t` would yield the same result, but that's not the case in python2, since `print` is a statement with its own syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` and use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead:

```
mytuple = (12, 18)
my_print('1fdsfd {0} -- {1}'.format(*mytuple)) # I've used the * here to unpack the tuple.
```

As others have pointed out, it converts `str1` into a tuple.

Comment: @Volatility I'm presuming the input is a tuple

Comment: Then use `my_print('1fdsfd {0} -- {1}'.format(*input_tuple))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unpacking all the arguments given to your function with the splat (`*`) operator, you are getting a tuple of arguments saved to `str1` eg.

```
>>> my_print('a', 'b')
---------------
('a', 'b')
---------------
```

Then you are simply printing the tuple of arguments, it seems like you don't need the splat since you only have `str1` so just remove it and it works fine.